# ¿Cómo habilitar el puerto 1433 de SQL SERVER 2014 en Windows 10?

Tags: sql

Antes en Windows 10 cuando buscaba el administrador de configuración de SQL SERVER 2014, se abría una ventana donde era muy sencillo habilitar el puerto y ponerle 1433, pero ahora ya no aparece, como acceso a esta ventana me urge en verdad.

Pongo una  captura en Windows 7 para que entiendan hasta donde quiero llegar 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: 1433, es el puerto por default no? de SQL, osea que debería estar asignado ya y por ende no es necesario que lo "habilites", ahora si lo que quieres es poder conectarte desde otra IP, solo necesitas abrir el puerto en el FIREWALL o el programa, darle permisos en firewall de windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copia esto en un fichero bat y ejecútalo, te abre todo lo que tiene que ver con sql server:

@echo =========  SQL Server Ports  ===================

@echo Enabling SQLServer default instance port 1433

netsh firewall set portopening TCP 1433 "SQLServer"

@echo Enabling Dedicated Admin Connection port 1434

netsh firewall set portopening TCP 1434 "SQL Admin Connection"

@echo Enabling conventional SQL Server Service Broker port 4022

netsh firewall set portopening TCP 4022 "SQL Service Broker"

@echo Enabling Transact-SQL Debugger/RPC port 135

netsh firewall set portopening TCP 135 "SQL Debugger/RPC"

@echo =========  Analysis Services Ports  ==============

@echo Enabling SSAS Default Instance port 2383

netsh firewall set portopening TCP 2383 "Analysis Services"

@echo Enabling SQL Server Browser Service port 2382

netsh firewall set portopening TCP 2382 "SQL Browser"

@echo =========  Misc Applications  ==============

@echo Enabling HTTP port 80

netsh firewall set portopening TCP 80 "HTTP"

@echo Enabling SSL port 443

netsh firewall set portopening TCP 443 "SSL"

@echo Enabling port for SQL Server Browser Service's 'Browse' Button

netsh firewall set portopening UDP 1434 "SQL Browser"

@echo Allowing multicast broadcast response on UDP (Browser Service Enumerations OK)

netsh firewall set multicastbroadcastresponse ENABLE

Tienes habilitado en la configuración del sql server el tipo de acceso?

Espero te sirva

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo hacerlo directamente a través del Firewall, también es muy sencillo, para ello puedes:

1. hacerlo a través del Panel o Buscarlo en la búsqueda de Windows.
2. Después seleccionas la opción "Configuración Avanzada".
3. En reglas de entrada le dices clic derecho "Nueva regla..."
4. Seleccionas la opción "Puerto"
5. Digitas el puerto, en este caso "1433"
6. Seleccionas la opción "Permitir conexión"
7. Marcas la opción que de deseas habilitar (por defecto están habilitadas todas).
8. Le das un nombre para identificar el puerto que esta está haciendo alusión ejemplo "SQL Server".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo mismo haces con la regla de salida

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que haya sido de tu ayuda.